# JAX-RS RESTful Service and permanent Oracle connection

Tags: java, oracle, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

I am writing a RESTful service which consumes `application/octet-stream` and accepts binary files to write them to disk (Tomcat 8, Windows Server 2012R2, JAX-RS). I then need to insert the file contents into an Oracle table.

The service itself runs fine, accepts files and writes them to disk.
My problem (or call it best-practice question) is, how to transfer the data to the Oracle DB. Of course I can open a connection in the service itsef which gets called everytime the service accepts a file, but is this really the "correct" way? We're talking about MANY small files (let's say 100 per minute, each about 300 byte in size).

Should I create a connection pool? Or even a standalone program which keeps the Oracle connection open permanently? Unfortunately, I can't really benchmark at the moment because I am on an isolated test server.

So, tl;dr: How to transfer the content of many small files accepted by a RESTful service to an Oracle DB?

Comment: Any of what you said works. I'd ask yourself the question if you want to make the webservice itself responsible for importing the files, or if you want to have another service be responsible for that. I'd only make the webservice dump the files in a staging location myself and process the files through another service from there. Keep the webservice thin, light and dumb.

Comment: @Gimby So should I run the second application as completely seperate service you think? Just checking the folder for new files and inserting them into the DB? I heartfully agree to keep the webservice simple and dumb, but I'd also like to have as few runnning programs as possible. Could I call the "open connection" and "transfer data to DB" functions from the original RESTful service?

Comment: I just read about asynchronous servlets. Maybe this could be my way to go. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are deploying on Tomcat, using the [Tomcat managed connection pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) is the most generic way. We use this and get very good performance out of it. You could roll your own and benchmark it, but I am not sure about the merits of this. I know I would try the way that's best integrated with Tomcat first and only if it does not perform move to libs like C3P0.

Depending on your use-case you could do without writing the files to disk and instead just insert them into the DB. Since your files are small, there would not even be a reason to go async or fork threads for insertion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll have a look at the Tomcat connection pool. I thought about the direct insert into the DB, too, but the connection to the DB sometimes is not 100% reliable. For updates or whatever it can also be down for 8h. By storing the files on the FS, I hope to gain some buffer for such outages.

Comment: Why not keep them in RAM? back of the envelope, over 8h that's just something like 13MB raw data - something like 100MB in Java RAM usage. Just use a static FIFO or something (unless your Tomcat gets shutdown as well)

Comment: Yeah that's the problem. The application server on which my Tomcat is installed may also be shut down. Unfortunately I have no control over the infrastructure itself.

Comment: I went with Tomcat connection pooling using [Oracle UCP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/connect.htm#CHDDCICA), so this will be my accepted answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Connection pools are the most generic way to go here. There's lots of reasons - separating the concerns of connection management from connection use, scalability control through configuration, overcoming the latency associated with connection setup,...

There's lots of implementations of simple connection pools out there, they can be found in application servers or libraries - c3p0 is a nice and easy one for a standalone, self-contained webapp.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I really wanted to discuss what practice in that specific case are best. Like, connections pools from the service itself? Connection pools from a second service? No connection pools at all or a "globally" opened DB connection, etc..

Comment: Configuring each service with its own connection pool is generally best practice. Although if you have a specific reason to share connections between services then you might use an application-server managed pool. I'm not sure I see how getting a connection from a 'separate' service would work, unless you mean that the separate service is really just a pool manager - in which case probably best to just let the application server manage the pool.